# Is it possible to skip some files when auto-converting to ARC?

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting my iOS project to ARC (about time, right?), but I'm running into a few issues with the `Convert to Objective-C ARC` tool.

I have gone through my entire project and removed any ARC-illegal calls (i.e., `release`, `autorelease`, `retain`, etc.). However, there are several files - all third party files - which I don't want to update to ARC. In my target build phases, I have added the flag `-fno-objc-arc` to each of these files, but when I run the `Convert to Objective-C ARC` tool, it continues to tell me that I need to update these files.

Is it possible to use the `Convert to Objective-C ARC` tool while still keeping specific files as non-ARC?

If not, is there a manual way to convert a project to ARC?

Comment: Ah! You are so right...I didn't see that I could click the project name and expand to see the individual files. I figures it had to be simple! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to uncheck the files from the ARC Convert Tool dialog:

[image]

Comment: Ah! You are so right...I didn't see that I could click the project name and expand to see the individual files. I figures it had to be simple! Thanks!!!

Comment: Learned this the hard way first time around too!  Please accept if possible.